# Find missing resources when loading a local file in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating some HTML page mockups and trying to view them in Firefox. Some of the dependent resources (mostly CSS files) are loaded dynamically through JavaScript. Unfortunately some of those resources don't exist or have the wrong path, so they can't be loaded.

How can I tell which resources Firefox can't load?

If this were running on a webserver, I could watch the `error_log` and I would see the 404 responses. But since I'm running locally, no such option exists. I suppose what I am looking for is an addon that can show me every resource being loaded by Firefox, as it is loading, since Firebug's Net tab does not work for local files.

Comment: Can you run a server on your computer, and then access the site via `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Adam you've been a member here for nearly two years and I never knew? LOL. You need to come visit [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local server (like [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/)) is the way to go.

Loading a page from file:// has many subtle differences from the http case. From your problem to some APIs not working on file:// to different security restrictions. Most importantly, there's no reason not to use a local web server since there are so easy to install ones.